# How can I use a regular expression to replace matches preserving case?

Tags: regex

How can I use a single regular expression to replace all words `town` with `village` preserving the case of the first letter of each match?

Example input:

```
Towns are small cities. I live in a town.
```

Desired output:

```
Villages are small cities. I live in a village.
```

Comment: Which regex engine? So you want Towns = Village? and town = village? Please write the expected output.

Comment: The right answer is not to try to do it in one regex. Just use two: `s/town/village/g; s/Town/Village/g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$_ = "Towns are small cities. I live in a town.\n";

s{ \b (?: (T)|(t) ) own       }
 { $1 ? "Village" : "village" }xge;

print;

# prints: Villages are small cities. I live in a village.
```

Comment: +1 For wizard - level regex :). So $1? is *defined* when T is matched? I had no idea this was possible inside a regex. You have to love perl..

Comment: Nice! But can you explain the syntax a little? Not sure I understand the `\b` and `xge` parts.

Comment: @cwd This is all described in the *perlre* manpage on your system, or in Chapter 5 of *Programming Perl*: `\b` is a “word boundary”; `/x` is a pattern modifier that allows whitespace and comments in patterns; `/g` is a substitution modifier that makes it do it globally not just once; `/e` is a substitution modifier that says the replacement portion of the substitution is not an interpolated string but rather a code block whose return value is used for the replacement. The pattern and code block are both syntax-checked and compiled at compile time, the very best time for such things to happen.