# Efficient String Search and Replace

Tags: regex, r, performance, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean about 2 million entries in a database consisting of job titles. Many have several abbreviations that I wish to change to a single consistent and more easily searchable option. So far I am simply running through the column with individual `mapply(gsub(...)` commands. But I have about 80 changes to make this way, so it takes almost 30 minutes to run.
There has got to be a better way. I'm new to string searching, I found the `*$` trick, which helped. Is there a way to do more than one search in a single `mapply`? I imagine that maybe faster?
Any help would be great. Thanks.

Here is some of the code below. Test is a column of 2 million individual job titles.

```
test <- mapply(gsub, " Admin ", " Administrator ", test)
test <- mapply(gsub, "Admin ", "Administrator ", test)
test <- mapply(gsub, " Admin*$", " Administrator", test)
test <- mapply(gsub, "Acc ", " Accounting ", test)
test <- mapply(gsub, " Admstr ", " Administrator ", test)
test <- mapply(gsub, " Anlyst ", " Analyst ", test)
test <- mapply(gsub, "Anlyst ", "Analyst ", test)
test <- mapply(gsub, " Asst ", " Assistant ", test)
test <- mapply(gsub, "Asst ", "Assistant ", test)
test <- mapply(gsub, " Assoc ", " Associate ", test)
test <- mapply(gsub, "Assoc ", "Associate ", test)
```

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171318/regex-for-preserving-case-pattern-capitalization/26171700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R solution which works.  You can define a data frame which will contain all patterns and their replacements.  Then you use `apply()` in row mode and call `gsub()` on your `test` vector for each pattern/replacement combination.  Here is sample code demonstrating this:

```
df <- data.frame(pattern=c(" Admin ", "Admin "),
                 replacement=c(" Administrator ", "Administrator "))

test <- c(" Admin ", "Admin ")

apply(df, 1, function(x) {
                test <<- gsub(x[1], x[2], test)
             })

> test
[1] " Administrator " "Administrator "
```

Comment: @thelatemail I have never seen this post, nor did I use SO to generate my answer.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you did (or that you did anything untoward at all) - just linking an old post so that questions are connected together.

Comment: Cool...no worries...thanks for adding this information.

Comment: @thelatemail I just noticed your comment once I answered lol. I have a similar answer in the link you provided.

Comment: @hwnd - :-D - I guess the only question now is whether `stri_replace....` functions would speed it up massively.

Comment: @thelatemail Definitely **stringi** - `STRINGI   56.203   62.0680   87.22181   80.6385  107.2740   271.727   100`

Comment: Thank you, this cut the run time by over a fourth and is along the lines of what I was thinking.

Comment: Thanks @Dick and feel free to upvote if you want :-)

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to use `mgsub` from `library(qdap)`

```
mgsub(patternVec, replaceVec, test)
```

#### data

```
patternVec <- c(" Admin ", "Admin ")
replaceVec <- c(" Administrator ",  "Administrator ")
```

Comment: @DickMcManus It may be worth trying essentially the same thing using the `stringi` library, which is supposed to be pretty efficient: `stri_replace_first_regex(test, patternVec, replaceVec)`.

Comment: @Jota - a quick test suggests that `stri` would be about 1.5x faster than just using a `for` loop, which should be faster than anything else here.