# Regex R substituting in a vector of replacements with parentheses

Tags: regex, r

Suppose I have a string `x` like so.

```
x <- "CTTTANNNNNNNYG"
```

I would like to replace each letter in x with a different string that may not be f the same length.

```
a <- c("A","C","G","T","W","S","M","K","R","Y","B","D","H","V","N")
b <- c("A","C","G","T","(A|T)","(C|G)","(A|C)","(G|T)","(A|G)","(C|T)","(C|G|T)","(A|G|T)","(A|C|T)","(A|C|G)","(A|C|G|T)")
```

If I wanted to replace the letters in vector a with the corresponding ones in vector b, I would want to manipulate string x into:

```
"CTTTA(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(C|T)G"
```

I've tried using `mapply(gsub, a,b,x)` and `str_replace()` to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171318/regex-for-preserving-case-pattern-capitalization/2617170

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since replacements are "fixed" and involve each just one letter, you can achieve the same result without using neither `regex` nor any additional packages. For instance:

```
vapply(strsplit(x,"",fixed=TRUE),function(z) paste(setNames(b,a)[z],collapse=""),"")
#[1] "CTTTA(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(C|T)G"
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `mgsub` from `library(qdap)`

```
library(qdap)
mgsub(a, b, x)
#[1] "CTTTA(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(C|T)G"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do this with base functions, you need to basically do each of the replacements sequentially (`gsub` isn't vectorized in this way). Here's one way to do that

```
Reduce(
    function(x, replace) {
        gsub(replace$pattern, replace$value, x)
    }, 
    Map(function(a,b) list(pattern=a, value=b), a, b), 
    init=x
)
# [1] "CTTTA(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(C|T)G"
```

We use `Map` to make pairs of match/replace values and then sequentially apply them to the string with `Reduce`