# Using purrr::reduce2 to replicate behaviour of nested gsub calls

Tags: r, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, purrr

Given sample string:

```
tst_str <- c("abc", "123", "klm", "lop")
```

I would like to make the following replacements:

- `abc -> za12`
- `123 -> poi`
- `klm -> uyt`

## Desired results

Simple nesting of `gsub` calls delivers the result:

```
gsub(
    pattern = "abc",
    replacement = "za12",
    x = gsub(
        pattern = "123",
        replacement = "poi",
        x = gsub(
            pattern = "klm",
            replacement = "uyt",
            x = tst_str
        )
    )
)
# [1] "za12" "poi"  "uyt"  "lop"
```

## Problem

I would like to arrive at identical results using `purrr::map*` or `purrr::reduce` functions. My initial take was to make use of `purrr::reduce2`

```
purrr::reduce2(
    .x = c("abc", "123", "klm"),
    .y = c("za12", "poi", "uyt"),
    .f = function(x, y, init) {
        gsub(pattern = x,
             replacement = y,
             x = init)
    },
    .init = tst_str
)
```

Clearly this is not the right way of doing that:

> Warning message: In gsub(pattern = x, replacement = y, x = init) :
>   argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be
>   used

---

## Notes

- The solution has to be based on [`purrr::`](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr) or other [*Higher Order Function*](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2010/09/23/higher-order-functions-in-r/)

  - [`do.call`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/do.call) can do as well
- The problem is not practical; [`multigsub`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qdap/versions/2.2.9/topics/multigsub) and similar functions solve such tasks easily.

Comment: This might be useful reading. A totally uncool `for` loop (or `Reduce` variation if you *have* to use higher order functions) is pretty efficient and terse - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171318/regex-for-preserving-case-pattern-capitalization/26171700

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for that, it's good approach. Also the benchmarking results are useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the right idea, try `reduce2` with `stringr::str_replace()`:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

tst_str <- c("abc", "123", "klm", "lop")
replacements <- c("za12", "poi", "uyt")
patterns <-  c("abc", "123", "klm")
reduce2(patterns, replacements, str_replace, .init=tst_str)

[1] "za12" "poi"  "uyt"  "lop"
```

Note that `.f` in `reduce2()` just [requires](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.4/topics/reduce) a function that takes 3 arguments.  You don't actually have to explicitly pass them in, `reduce` will take care of that.

Alternately (although not higher-order):

```
names(replacements) <- patterns
str_replace_all(tst_str, replacements)
```