# Match and replace words in char-vector

Tags: r

I have a vector with text lines in it, like this:

```
text<-c("Seat 1: 7e7389e3 ($2 in chips)","Seat 3: 6786517b ($1.67 in chips)","Seat 4: 878b0b52 ($2.16 in chips)","Seat 5: a822375 ($2.37 in chips)","Seat 6: 7a6252e6 ($2.51 in chips)")
```

And I have to replace some words with other words, that i have in a dataframe like this:

```
df<-data.frame(codigo=c("7e7389e3","6786517b","878b0b52","a822375","7a6252e6"),
name=c("lucas","alan","ivan","lucio","donald"))
```

So I would like to 1) Grab the first line of "text" 2) Check if there is any word to replace in df 3) Replace it 4) Do the same with the next "text" line and so on. In order to have something like this:

```
[1] "Seat 1: lucas ($2 in chips)"
[2] "Seat 3: alan ($1.67 in chips)"
[3] "Seat 4: ivan ($2.16 in chips)"
[4] "Seat 5: lucio ($2.37 in chips)"
[5] "Seat 6: donald ($2.51 in chips)"
```

There is any formula to do this?

Answer (score 2):

We can do this easily with `str_replace_all` which can take a named vector

```
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
str_replace_all(text, deframe(df))
#[1] "Seat 1: lucas ($2 in chips)"  
#[2] "Seat 3: alan ($1.67 in chips)" 
#[3]  "Seat 4: ivan ($2.16 in chips)"  
#[4] "Seat 5: lucio ($2.37 in chips)" 
#[5] "Seat 6: donald ($2.51 in chips)"
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `sapply` + `gsub` + `Vectorize`

```
unname(sapply(text,function(x) (u <- Vectorize(gsub)(df$codigo,df$name,x,fixed = TRUE))[u!=x]))
```

which gives

```
[1] "Seat 1: lucas ($2 in chips)"     "Seat 3: alan ($1.67 in chips)"
[3] "Seat 4: ivan ($2.16 in chips)"   "Seat 5: lucio ($2.37 in chips)"
[5] "Seat 6: donald ($2.51 in chips)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Cases like this are a perfect occasion to use a `for` loop. It's boring, but it works, and is reasonably competitive in efficiency terms as per this previous question - [regex for preserving case pattern, capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171318/regex-for-preserving-case-pattern-capitalization/26171700)

```
out <- text
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df)) ) {
    out <- gsub(df$codigo[i], df$name[i], out)
}
out
#[1] "Seat 1: lucas ($2 in chips)"     "Seat 3: alan ($1.67 in chips)"  
#[3] "Seat 4: ivan ($2.16 in chips)"   "Seat 5: lucio ($2.37 in chips)" 
#[5] "Seat 6: donald ($2.51 in chips)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach using `tidyverse` functions. It looks like, if there is a pattern with `:`  and  `(`, you can assign a common split element and the separate by column, join with `df` and finally concatenate the strings to get the expected result. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
res <- text %>% as.data.frame %>% setNames(.,'v1') %>%
  mutate(v1=gsub(': ','*',v1),
         v1=gsub(' (','*',v1,fixed=T)) %>%
  separate(v1,c('Var1','codigo','Var3'),sep='\\*') %>%
  left_join(df) %>%
  mutate(Out=paste0(Var1,': ',name,' (',Var3)) %>%
  select(Out)
```

Output:

```
                              Out
1     Seat 1: lucas ($2 in chips)
2   Seat 3: alan ($1.67 in chips)
3   Seat 4: ivan ($2.16 in chips)
4  Seat 5: lucio ($2.37 in chips)
5 Seat 6: donald ($2.51 in chips)
```