# File renaming (string substitution) without a clear pattern using R

Tags: r, string, rename, substitution, file-rename

Currently, I am working with a long list of files.
They have a name pattern of SB_xxx_(parts). (different extensions), where xxx refers to an item code.

```
SB_19842.png
SB_19842_head.png
SB_19842_hand.png
SB_19842_head.pdf
...
```

It is found that many of these codes have incorrect entries.
I got two columns in hand: One is for old codes and one is new codes (let's say A & B). I hope to change all those old codes in the file names to the new code.

```
  old    new
12154  24124
92482  02425
    .....
```

My first thought is to use `file.rename()`
However, it is a one-to-one changing approach. I cannot do this because every item has a different number of parts and different file extensions.

Is there any recursive method that can simply change all incorrect file names with strings in A and replace them with strings in B? Anyone get an idea, please?

Comment: Something like this should cover it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64597819/match-and-replace-words-in-char-vector/64601011

Answer (score 0):

A loop solution with `purrr::map2` at the end:

```
library(purrr)
#create files to rename
file.create("SB_19842.png")
file.create("SB_19842_head.png")
file.create("SB_19842_hand.png")
file.create("SB_19842_head.pdf")
file.create("SB_12154.png")
file.create("SB_12154_head.png")
file.create("SB_12154_hand.png")
file.create("SB_12154_head.pdf")
# a dataframe with old a nd new patterns
file_names <- data.frame(
  old = c("19842", "12154"),
  new = c("new1", "new2")
)
# old filenames from the directory, specify path if needed
file_names_SB <- list.files(pattern = "SB_")
# function to substitute one type of code with another
sub_one_code <- function(old_code, new_code, file_names_original){
  gsub(paste0("SB_", old_code), paste0("SB_", new_code), file_names_original)
}
# loop to substitute all codes
new_file_names <- file_names_SB
for (row in 1:nrow(file_names)){
  new_file_names <- sub_one_code(file_names[row, "old"], file_names[row, "new"], new_file_names)
}
# rename all the files
map2(file_names_SB,
     new_file_names,
     file.rename)
```

@thelatemail provided a link with more elegant solutions for generating new file names.