# Regex R: Remove strings from text by using a vector string

Tags: r, regex, string

```
names <- c('Laars Anderson', 'Peter Grabowski')
text <- c('Laars Anderson needs to bla bla bla, reply from Peter Grabowski')
output <- c('needs to bla bla bla, reply from')
```

I'm using regex to clean up my text for text mining purpose. The text is mostly about email conversations with lots irrelevant words for the final analysis such as names, emails, etc.

I have the employee names list and want to use this list of names to remove their names from the text emails.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to the @Ronak answer, but uses proper word boundaries and whitespace patterns for a cleaner approach:

```r
names <- c('Laars Anderson', 'Peter Grabowski')
text <- 'Laars Anderson needs to bla bla bla Peter Grabowski, reply from Peter Grabowski'
regex <- paste0("\\b\\s*(?:", paste0(names, collapse="|"), ")\\b\\s*")
output = trimws(gsub(regex, " ", text))
output

[1] "needs to bla bla bla , reply from"
```

If your `names` vector be *really* large, to the point where the regex engine can't handle the size of the alternation, then you can always just iterate and make replacements:

```r
names <- c('Laars Anderson', 'Peter Grabowski')
text <- 'Laars Anderson needs to bla bla bla Peter Grabowski, reply from Peter Grabowski'
for (name in names) {
    text <- gsub(paste0("\\b\\s*", name, "\\s*\\b"), "", text)
}
text <- trimws(text)
text

[1] "needs to bla bla bla, reply from"
```

Comment: Thanks, are you familiar with this error though? `Error in gsub(regex, " ", text) : 
  assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634` My names vector is pretty long, more than 10,000 user names. Alternatives I found that some ask to use mgsub from qdap library or split this user name vector into smaller chunk

Comment: @AfiqJohari I'm actually not familiar with that error, but I know the cause.  It's that the alternation is too big.  Let me edit my question with a workaround.

Comment: @AfiqJohari, if the `for` loop seems slow, I wonder whether there's a justification to switch to a simpler `gsub` with `fixed = TRUE` rather than handling word boundaries and whitespace. Any thoughts, Tim?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 if `fixed=TRUE`, it will fail on zero-length pattern `Error in gsub(pattern = name, replacement = "", comment, fixed = TRUE) : 
  zero-length pattern`

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 I retract my earlier comment.  Setting fixed to TRUE means we can't use a regex alternation, so sadly that's not an option.  However, we _could_ try removing word boundaries and whitespace.  That might speed things up a bit.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `stri_replace_all` from the "stringi" package:

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_fixed(text, names, "", vectorize_all=FALSE)
## [1] " needs to bla bla bla, reply from "
```

Get rid of the leading and trailing whitespace with `trimws`.

Comment: This old question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26171700/496803 - can be adapted for this sort of thing in a vectorised fashion, including a pretty interesting `Reduce` option from Flodel - `Reduce(function(str, args) gsub(args, "", str), names, init = text)`

Comment: I was initially going to post a `for` loop since it also seemed that the option for `fixed = TRUE` would be helpful. (+1 to you over there). That `Reduce` approach is great too!

Comment: The `Reduce` adaption thoroughly confused me the first time I saw it. And the second and third times too.

Comment: `Warning messages:
1: In stri_replace_all_fixed(text, names, "", vectorize_all = FALSE) :
  empty search patterns are not supported` some edge cases here, the actual names vector is around 10,000, And the text may contain Danish characters. Just in case, I've did some prior cleaning on the text to remove special characters. Thanks, really appreciate this

Comment: @AfiqJohari, I think that Tim's `for` loop is going to be one of the better approaches, and it shouldn't be a problem in terms of performance. If you can isolate a  vector that generates the warning you've shared here, that would be helpful with further troubleshooting.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 thanks for that, I still find `for` loop pretty slow but it works for the time being. I'll create another question once I got a better understanding on the cause.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
names <- c('Laars Anderson', 'Peter Grabowski')
text <- c('Laars Anderson needs to bla bla bla, reply from Peter Grabowski')

gsub(paste0(names, collapse = ' | '), '', text)
#[1] "needs to bla bla bla, reply from"
```

Comment: Thanks @ronak, the solutions work for the reproducible example above, but I guess there're some limitations on the actual length of the vector name to be used. `Error in gsub(paste0(names, collapse = " | "), "", text) : 
  assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634`, I tried the mgsub alternative function from qdap, but the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In case `names` is too long for the regex engine you can use `Reduce` to loop to each name.

```
trimws(Reduce(function(x,y) gsub(y, "", x), paste0("\\b", names, "\\b"), text))
#[1] "needs to bla bla bla, reply from"
```

or using perl:

```
trimws(gsub(paste0("\\b", names, "\\b", collapse="|"), "", text, perl=TRUE))
```