How can I subtract a number from string elements in R?
I have a long string. The part is
x <- "Text1 q10_1 text2 q17 text3 q22_5 ..."

How can I subtract 1 from each number after "q" letter to obtain the following?
y <- "Text1 q9_1 text2 q16 text3 q21_5 ..."

I can extract all my numbers from x:
numbers <- stringr::str_extract_all(x, "(?<=q)\\d+")
numbers <- as.integer(numbers[[1]]) - 1

But how can I update x with these new numbers?
The following is not working
stringr::str_replace_all(x, "(?<=q)\\d+", as.character(numbers))


I learned today that stringr::str_replace_all will take a function:
stringr::str_replace_all(
  x, 
  "(?<=q)\\d+", 
  \(x) as.character(as.integer(x) - 1)
)


Yes it's nice isn't it? JavaScript and Python support this too. If you're interested in how this is done in other languages it's covered in answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171318/regex-for-preserving-case-pattern-capitalization/76497678

We can use gregexpr and regmatches for this:
x <- "Text1 q10_1 text2 q17 text3 q22_5 ..."
gre <- gregexpr("(?<=q)[0-9]+", x, perl = TRUE)
regmatches(x, gre)
# [[1]]
# [1] "10" "17" "22"
regmatches(x, gre) <- lapply(regmatches(x, gre), function(z) as.integer(z) - 1L)
x
# [1] "Text1 q9_1 text2 q16 text3 q21_5 ..."


Here is an alternative approach using gsubfn function from gsubfn package:

gsubfn matches "q" followed by one or more digits.
The digits are captured as a group.
Each captured group is passed to the inline function ~ paste0("q", as.numeric(x) - 1) which converts the captured digits into numeric values and subtracts 1, and then concatenates it back.

#install.packages("gsubfn")
library(gsubfn)

gsubfn("q(\\d+)", ~ paste0("q", as.numeric(x) - 1), x)

"Text1 q9_1 text2 q16 text3 q21_5 ..."


That package never ceases to amaze me, nice!

Here is a rather convoluted solution that should still work:
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)
x <- "Text1 q10_1 text2 q17 text3 q22_5 ..."

x <- data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) #Convert to data.frame

x %<>% 
  separate_longer_delim(cols = everything(), " ") %>% #Split the string into separate rows.
  mutate(s = as.numeric(str_extract(x, "(?<=q)[0-9]+"))-1) %>% #Extract the value and subtract 1 from it.
  mutate(x1 = str_replace(x, "(?<=q)[0-9]+", as.character(s))) %>% #Replace the value with this new value.
  select(x1) %>% #Retain only data necessary to produce the output.
  mutate(x1 = paste0(x1, collapse = " ")) %>% #Collapse this into a string.
  distinct(x1) #Discard superfluous copies of the string.

x <- x$x1
x
# [1] "Text1 q9_1 text2 q16 text3 q21_5 ..."


here is a python version that uses logic in place of regular expressions. It can probably be cleaned up a bit...
x = "Text1 q10_1 text2 q17 text3 q22_5 ..."


list_x = x.split()
list_y = []

for y in list_x:
    if y[0] == 'q':
        
        z = y.find('_')
        if z == -1: 
            z = None
            end = ''
        else: end = y[z:] 
        r = int(y[1:z])
        r = r-1
        r_string = 'q' + str(r) + str(end)
        
    else:
        r_string = y
    list_y.append(r_string)

final = ' '.join(list_y)
print(final)

The result is:
Text1 q9_1 text2 q16 text3 q21_5 ...

Having shown the above, regex is a more suitable method.
